# How to add touch event for horizontal card drag?

Tags: javascript

I tried building a set of cards which I could drag for horizontal scroll. Mouse events are working as intended, but I'm not sure why touch events are not working. These are the action events listner I added for mouse and touch. Any help would be great.

```
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if(!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX); //scroll-fast
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  console.log(walk);
});
slider.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
}); 
     slider.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
  if(!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX); //scroll-fast
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  console.log(walk);
});
```

Comment: Please add some markup